# How to create a observer in laravel using command

Tags: laravel-5

I need to create an observer using the laravel artisan command. I tried many ways but can't find the right way.

Comment: Pro tip: If you run `php artisan` you can see all available commands ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have been are using laravel 5.5, the artisan comman is available only from Laravel 5.6

Please upgrade your framework in composer.json and change laravel 5.5 to Laravel 5.6. and then you can run `php artisan make:observer Test`